# How install Java6 with 64?

Tags: java, 64-bit, ubuntu-14.04

I'm new to Ubuntu and java i searched more about installation for `java 6` on `Ubuntu 14.04 64bit`

but can't get any solution until now

can i find help here ?

Comment: Did you see this  :http://askubuntu.com/questions/234594/installing-java-on-ubuntu-64-bit

Comment: Why? Install Java 8. All other versions don't get any public updates anymore. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html

Comment: i imported a project using java6 and by searching found that there are problems with java 7 and projects built on java6

Comment: the problem i guess that in using old version of java for new version of Ubuntu ! or there is no problem there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the easiest way I know and as a beginner you would appreciate the use of apt-get for ubuntu.

sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk

This line of code should do it.Hope this helps :D

Comment: i started to install by apt-get install oracle-java6-installer!! right or not ?

Comment: Inorder to perform the apt-get install oracle-java6-installer, first you might need to have to add repository:  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java  and I dont prefer oracle java because it is not maintained/patched anymore.

Comment: thanks , what do you mean by not maintained/patched anymore ?

Comment: I am really sorry for the late reply. I meant to say oracle java6 isnt being maintained anymore i guess :)